# Batch processing images in image J. Attempting to add a series of images

Tags: batch-processing, tiff, imagej

I am attempting to add multiple DICOM images together to for one summated image. This is the code I have come up with so far. It adds the first two images, and saves the new 'sum' image. It will then add one more of the images, but the for loop does not seem to be working and none of the other 17 images in the directory will be added. No error messages are shown.

```
dir = getDirectory("Choose a Directory "); 
list = getFileList(dir);
open(dir+list[0])
open(dir+list[1])
imageCalculator("Add create", list[0], list[1]);
saveAs("Tiff", dir+"Sum.tif");
close();
selectWindow(list[0]);
close();
selectWindow(list[1]);
close();
if (getVersion>="1.40e")
    setOption("display labels", true);
setBatchMode(true);
open(dir+"Sum.tif");
for (i=3; i<list.length; i++) {
    if (nImages>=1) {
    path = dir+list[i];
        open(path);
        imageCalculator("Add", "Sum.tif", list[i]);
        selectWindow(list[i]);
        close();
saveAs("Tiff", dir+"Sum1.tif");
}
```

Comment: I don't know ImageJ, or even recognise the language of your question, and you don't really describe in any detail what goes wrong, however I wonder if your aggregate image is maybe of too small a type (e.g. only 8-bit) to sum multiple images. Maybe you need to cast it up to int32 or similar. Just a thought.

Comment: Hi Mark, as far as I am aware the language is Java. Essentially, the issue is that the for loop will only open up one image and add it to the 'sum' image, and does not add any of the other images in the directory (there are 19). No errors present. I think that the image type is okay as I can do the process manually without any problem (but i may be wrong!). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Script seems like ImageJ macro to me. If I were you I would simplify the task by stacking all your images together and Z-projecting the sum of them, which comes out to something simple:

```
dir = getDirectory("Choose a Directory "); 
list = getFileList(dir);
for (i=0; i<list.length; i++) {
    open(dir+list[i]);
}
run("Images to Stack", "name=[Stack of DICOMs] title=[]");
run("Z Project...", "projection=[Sum Slices]");
```

The product of the above code should change the image type to 32 bit by default to hold larger values if necessary. By the way, you are missing semicolons in your script when opening files. You may not have included all your code because some crucial brackets to end your loops are missing.